# Impersonation Error

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the below error in c# code after the impersonation.

{"Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated."}

It is plain WPF windows application. In the begining of the application Impersonated the different user. Getting this error in random location.

Comment: How did you achieve impersonation in a WPF app? If you don't play with the tokens with enough care, this kind of error message can occur. So please provide more details on your attempt.

Comment: I used the Impersonator class from http://pastebin.com/EmKYDN6R

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and the solution is to have impersonation context at the actual task level rather than having all tasks performed under a single impersonation context. Earlier when I used impersonation context right from the button click event, I was performing all related tasks under the hood, but realized the impersonation context was failing between the tasks. So once I separated the context to have it exclusively for each of the tasks, everything worked fine! good luck.

Comment: Just wanted to say that you are awesome!  I've been banging my head against the wall all day with this same problem, and your advice immediately got me to refactor my code, and now everything is working just fine.  Thanks!